# How to use memmove with pointer of pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following struct in C:

```
typedef struct {
double value;
char* name;
} COMPONENT;
```

And I have the following vector of pointers:

```
COMPONENT **list = malloc(sizeof(COMPONENT*)*100);
```

This list contains only 10 pointers of COMPONENT struct even allocated for 100 elements, ok. Now, I want to insert at the first position a new COMPONENT using the memmove:

```
memmove(list+sizeof(COMPONENT*), list, sizeof(COMPONENT*)*10);
list[0] = new_element_ptr;
```

But this operation is not working =[. I'm losing all other references (list[1], list[2] and so on...). Is this differents because it is a struct and my vector have only pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
memmove(list + 1, list, sizeof(list[0]) * 10);
```

When adding to pointers, you are not adding byte offsets, you are adding number of elements.

Comment: Humm this works! Then, if I want to put a element in a specific index of this list, this is like it: size_t copy_size = sizeof(list[0]) * (10 - where); memmove(list+where+1, list+where, copy_size); list[where] = new_element_ptr; ? the variable where here is the index

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't know about it for vector of pointers in C. An important lesson! Thanks!